# Pundit Multiple Roles Index Spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, pundit

I have the following spec, policy and controller. For some reason, my permissions' index spec for *business user* is not passing, but it works on the front-end. My spec might be wrong or I might be overlooking something. Many thanks in advance for help.

**App Policy**

```
class AppPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :model

  def initialize(user, model)
    @user = user
    @app = model
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)

       @user = user
       @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      if user.super_user? || user.admin?
        scope.all
      elsif user.business_user? || user.user?
        scope.where(user_id: user.id)
      else
        scope.none
      end
    end
  end

  def index?
    @user.admin? || @user.super_user?|| @user.apps || @user == @apps.user
  end
```

** App Controller**

```
class AppController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @apps = policy_scope(App).order(:name).page(params[:page]).per(25)
    authorize @apps
    @user = current_user
  end
```

** App Policy Spec**

```
  describe AppPolicy do
    subject { AppPolicy }

    let (:other_user) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user }
    let (:business_user) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user, :business_user }
    let (:admin) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user, :admin }
    let (:super_user) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user, :super_user }
    let (:app) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :app }

    permissions :index? do
        it "allows access for a regular user" do
          expect(AppPolicy).to permit(app.user, app)
        end
      #failing spec below
        it "denies access for a business user" do
          expect(AppPolicy).not_to permit(business_user, app)
        end
        it "allows access for an admin" do
          expect(AppPolicy).to permit(admin, app)
        end
        it "allows access for an super user" do
          expect(AppPolicy).to permit(super_user, app)
        end
      end
```

** Update **

I was testing the wrong things. Will post answer on my solution.